# Special configuration of the vhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, debian, vhosts

I've got some headache trying to configure that for some days so I hope someone can help me.

I've got few sites, each one related to an FTP account. I would like to make them accessible through my man website by the url `http://www.mainsite.com/site1`. At this point an Alias should do the work.

However I would like to add some features such as specify the log file related to the site1 which would be in the web directory of the FTP account site1. Later, I would like to put them in /var/log and have a script to sync the log file located in the web directory with the one in /var/log so that even if a user delete the log file in the web directory, the original one is still here.

To go back to the main problem, I don't know how to do that, I tried to configure a whole vhost for the site1 but then, as the ServerName would be the same as the main site, the main site would no longer be accessible.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the ancient ServerPath directive, which will cause /site1 to be mapped to one vhost and /site2 to be mapped to another, despite having matching servername and local interface:port.

Comment: It's quite interesting but is it feasable ? I'm mean in all the examples I've seen it was with subdomains placed in the same web directory, here that's not the case : the directory for mysite and the one for site1 are in completely different folders.

Comment: It's URL based, not filesystem based, so it's feasible.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll be working on it then :)